# How to search geo-point with polygon across dateline?

Tags: elasticsearch, polygon, geo

How to search geo-point with polygon across dateline(International Date Line,or 180 and -180 longitude) use java api?

Hello everyone:

I use ElasticSearch 2.1 and its java api, I want to **search documents with polygon geo filter(the polygon is rectangle usually)**,but **when the polygon across the dateline** (International Date Line,or 180 and -180 longitude)**,it go wrong**. For example:
My code:

```
BoolQueryBuilder mustQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
......
GeoPolygonQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.geoPolygonQuery("description.device_location.es_geo");

qb.addPoint(0,100);//the left down vertex of the polygon(rectangle),patams is (lat , lon)
qb.addPoint(0,-170);//right down
qb.addPoint(80,-170);//right up
qb.addPoint(80,100);//left up
qb.addPoint(0,100);//left down,same to the first vertex

mustQuery = mustQuery.must(qb);
SearchResponse searchResponse = EsClient.getClient().prepareSearch(Config.indexName)
.setTypes(Config.typeName)
.setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
.setQuery(mustQuery)
.setFrom(0).setSize(size).setExplain(true)
.execute()
.actionGet();
```

diagrammatic sketch:

[I want search in A area，but ES search in B area in fact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2e1I.jpg)

As the picture above, I provide ES points [0,100],[0,-170],[80,-170],[80,100],[0,100] to describe A area,and **I want docs in A area**, A area across dteline.
 But according to the result, there is longitude 82,98,-121 etc., but no docs between [100,180]and between [-180,-170],so I suppose **ES search in B area in fact**(It analyze the polygon in error).

I search for the solution , on the ES's website, I found some words about this problem:
(form www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/geo-shape.html)

> IMPORTANT NOTE: GeoJSON does not mandate a specific order for vertices thus ambiguous polygons around the dateline and poles are possible. To alleviate ambiguity the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Simple Feature Access specification defines the following vertex ordering:

- > Outer Ring - Counterclockwise
- > Inner Ring(s) / Holes - Clockwise

> For polygons that do not cross the dateline, vertex order will not matter in Elasticsearch. For polygons that do cross the dateline, Elasticsearch requires vertex ordering to comply with the OGC specification. Otherwise, an unintended polygon may be created and unexpected query/filter results will be returned.
>
> The following provides an example of an ambiguous polygon. Elasticsearch will apply OGC standards to eliminate ambiguity resulting in a polygon that crosses the dateline.

But this is for  geo-Shape datatype, and  my docs' location is geo-point, I can't found similar words on geo-points's webpage(www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/geo-point.html).

I hava try some way:
1. Counterclockwise and clockwise vertex  order;
2. start from every vertex of rectangle;
3. replace -170 lon with 190 lon;
but these ways all don't work.

Does anyone know how to search with a polygon across dateline ?
Thanks!
(sorry, I'm a Chinese developer and I can't speak English well, if there is solecism,please give me advice or comments, thank you.)

[Here is the translated text of Chinese.Chinese characters couldn't be insert to question direct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUjZb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the asker, and I have an answer already.
I have ask this question at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/search-geo-point-with-polygon-across-dateline/39103/3 ,and get answer there.
Before,I have ever think if there isn't perfect solution,I can **split the polygon into 2 by dateline**.I have know ES don't suport to search geo-point with polygon across dateline now:

At the moment `geo_polygon` queries for `geo_point` types do not work
across the dateline. You will either have to:

1. manually split the polygon into 2 and combine them using a boolean AND;
2. reindex the `geo_points` as `geo_shapes` (recommend setting `points_only = true`) and using a geo_shape (www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/geo-shape.html) query.

But if you know the polygon is a
rectangle, you can use a geo_bounding_box (www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html) query which will properly
handle the dateline (as in your example).

Thanks for @nknize and @medcl1 (at discuss.elastic.co)!